# Python: is SimpleHTTPServer only capable of serving directory?

Tags: bash, python-2.7, simplehttpserver, dynamic-pages

I have some experience in `nodejs` and `php` and almost zero experience in `python`, and I need to write a very simple 1-page script on my small VM which takes input through `GET` and executes some `bash` commands based on the input. So I thought python would be better suited for it since it already comes pre-installed with `ubuntu`, plus it would provide me an opportunity to start learning `python`. 
 
 I Googled all day and only found references to `SimpleHTTPServer` which only seems to be for delivering static server-side web-pages. Where do I start in `python` to achieve a mix of dynamic server-side pages and `bash` scripting with minimum additional installation and configuration?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Try flask, which suit your purpose. (Less or no configuration) (dynamic) (server side page rendering) (also execute scripts on server).

Comment: @Cyrus: that was the point of my question, I didn't even know where to begin to even start simple writing hello world dynamic page.

Comment: @Reck: thanks, I will give it a shot..